# Why PHP curl subject not matching?

Tags: php, curl, ssl

We have a self-signed certificate with common name for the domain "assistent.local" all subdomains.

Curl does not seem to understand this:

> CURL error #51: SSL: certificate subject name
>   '*.assistent.local/CN=assistent.local' does not match target host name
>   'auth.assistent.local'

What is the problem?

Comment: does it work in Browser?

Comment: the certificate was generated using `assistent.local` your using `auth.assistent.local` to access it

Comment: yeap, no problems, instuctions found here: http://serverfault.com/questions/256216/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-for-more-than-one-subdomain

Comment: @DevZer0, no it was generated using `*.assistent.local/CN=assistent.local`

Comment: Looks like you needed `CN=*....`

Comment: Seems like curl does not support this kind of naming (domain and subdomains). I've generated a cert for `*.assistent.local` only and the error was gone.